# Concatenating the list elements in R

Tags: string, r, list

I have a list where each element contains the string as follows:

```
[[1]] 
 [1] 
 "diane"    "bradbury"

[[2]] 
 [1] "diane"    "bradbury"

 [[3]] 
  [1] "derek" "legg"
```

and what I need to obtains is one-column data frame like this:

```
"diane bradbury" 
"diane bradbury" 
"derek legg"
```

Can you please advise?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `paste` with `sapply`:

```
myList <- list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"), c("E", "F"))

myList
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C" "D"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "E" "F"

sapply(myList, paste, collapse = " ")
# [1] "A B" "C D" "E F"
```